# background-size в псевдокласе

Tags: css, css3, sass

Всем привет.
Не первый раз натыкаюсь на такой артефакт, что у блоков с одинаковым классом, но разными фонами заданными через :nth-child(), не срабатывает background-size заданный непосредственно в самом классе. Почему так происходит?

```
.newKkmPlate
    width: calc(100% / 4)
    color: var(--color-white)
    background: var(--color-textColor)
    // Не работает
    background-size: cover
    &:nth-child(2)
        background: url('../images/newItemPlateBg_1.jpg')
        // Работает
        background-size: cover
    &:nth-child(4)
        background: url('../images/newItemPlateBg_2.jpg')
```

Comment: Потому что свойство `background` включает в себя и `background-size` тоже ([справка](https://webref.ru/css/background)). Когда вы используете `background`, вы затираете старое значение `background-size`

Comment: @andreymal Действительно, даже не подумал об этом. Можете оформить ответ, поставлю галочку. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это, конечно же не артефакт.
Посмотрите внимательней, вы задаёте фоновое изображение через свойство `background`, которое просто напросто перезаписывает `background-size`, указанный в базовом перечне правил для класса.

В таких случаях предпочтительней использовать непосредственно те свойства, которые вы хотите переопределить:

Попробуйте так:

```
.newKkmPlate
    width: calc(100% / 4)
    color: var(--color-white)
    background: var(--color-textColor)
    background-size: cover
    &:nth-child(2)
        background-image: url('../images/newItemPlateBg_1.jpg')
    &:nth-child(4)
        background-image: url('../images/newItemPlateBg_2.jpg')
```

Удачи!